# Mock elastic search data

Tags: java, junit, mockito

How do I mock elastic search data. In the below code `rs` is an interface which is implemented by `ElasticSearchDriver` class. `rs` will have elastic search db details which inturn gets added in the results.

While writing unit tests for this code how do we mock the elastic search data.

```
ListThread listThread = new ListThread(rs, index, QueryMap, sortOrder)
results.add(executor.submit(listThread));
```

Comment: Are you able to pass in the listThread to the method?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? Did you mean to use mock instead of ES i.e returning data from mock object rather than ES?